# Как получить доступ к уже запущенному экземпляру таймера? (фрагменты, CountDownTimer)

Tags: android, android-fragment

В приложении использую фрагменты.

На одном из них пользователь может выставить таймер на закрытие приложения.

Таймер реализован с помощью `CountDownTimer`.

Если запустить таймер и перейти на другой фрагмент, то `CountDownTimer` продолжит работу и закроет приложение. Но если опять открыть фрагмент с таймером - открывается новый экземпляр и нет доступа к управлению уже запущенным таймером (отменить, изменить время).

Подскажите, как получить доступ к уже запущенному экземпляру таймера?

Comment: таймер можно запускать не во фрагменте, а в сервисе. а во фрагменте только контролировать запуски или получать необходимую информацию

Answer (score 1):

Alarm Manager в помощь, а на будущее, если вы профукали ссылку на объект, то до него никак не достучаться

Answer (score 1):

Сделал как посоветовал @andreich в комментарии - все работает.

---

Таймер можно запускать не во фрагменте, а в сервисе. а во фрагменте только контролировать запуски или получать необходимую информацию

---

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Также вы можете отметить ответ, который вам помог, галочкой. Так остальным будет видно, что этот ответ сработал для вас.